# Soundcloud API embed private playlist

Tags: python, soundcloud

I would like to use the Soundcloud API (Python SDK) to create a private (temporary) playlist and embed that to a website.

So this is not working unfortunatlely. If the playlist is public it works, but if it's private it doesn't.

```
client.post('/playlists', playlist={
        'title': 'some title',
        'sharing': 'private',
        'embeddable_by' : 'all',
        'tracks': tracks })
```

While creatig the playlist I can set 'embeddale_by' to 'me' or 'all'. I also played wih that and nothing. 
Apparently it should be possible to make private tracks embaddable using the UI, but I want to do it programmatically.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does not work? embeding the private playlist? i guess you need a secret token for that. https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#playlists

Comment: Creating the embed-code with: embed = client.get('/oembed', url=playlist_url, allow_redirects=True).html                           When I try to get the secret-token directly to create the embed code myself I get the same Unautorized Exception.